# The accuracy test of word2vec in gensim

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I'm currently use gensim to reproduce the result of example of Google provide. [here](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/)

The problem is the accuracy test of gensim doesn't match with Google's result.

For example, the accuracy of capital-common-countries of Google is 82.02%, the best result of gensim of different parameter sets is 64.4%. There is a big gap here.

Here is the code snippet of train word2vec and accuracy by using gensim

```
sentences = word2vec.Text8Corpus('./text8')
model = word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences, size=200, workers=12, min_count=5, sg=0, window=8, iter=15, sample=1e-4, negative=25)
model.accuracy("./questions-words.txt")[enter image description here][2]
```

Code snippet of Google's demo without changes any parameters

```
 ./demo-word-accuracy.sh
```

[Accuracy comparison detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dhUK.png)

Does anyone could help on this?

Answer (score 4):

Try `alpha=0.05` and `cbow_mean=1`. The word2vec.c code automatically shifts to those starting defaults when in CBOW mode, but gensim doesn't. To reduce sources of confusion gensim may more closely match the word2vec.c defaults in the future: https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/issues/534

Comment: Thanks for help! it do solve my problem by addthing alpha=0.05 & cbow_mean=1. It is very help to look through https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gensim/ggCHGncd5rU/Z_pQDD69AAAJ.   However, it takes me 560s to train this model, which is much slower than google's version(385s), do you have any idea about how to accelerate it?